# I'm looking for a statistical test more robust than the sign test for my experimental analysis

Tags: experiment-design, wilcoxon-signed-rank, compositional-data, sign-test

I made an exploratory experiment that consists of a pair of readings. I used Scanning Electron Microscopy-Energy Dispersive Spectroscopy (SEM-EDS) to read elements on several mineral surfaces, getting a proportion of the elements I established as a response.

I did this for several samples using the same set of elements for all of them, then I used the samples in a 3-month experiment, recovering the samples afterwards and making readings again using the same parameters and positions. This gave me another set of elemental proportions for each sample.

(E.g., 50% oxygen, 20% calcium, 10% sodium, 20% iron (before) and 53% oxygen, 17% calcium, 15% sodium, 15% iron (after))

The readings before the 3-month experiment are the "before" readings, and after 3-months were the "after" readings.

So now I have a pair of "before" and "after" readings for every element I read in each sample, for a total of 16 samples. I know this is not the best statistical set up, but this was supposed to be  an exploratory analysis, and I'm trying to make the best of it. I talked to someone with statistical knowledge, and she suggested the sign test, which I did (on R) using "Nonparametric statistics for the behavioral sciences" by Siegel and Castellan.

The H0 I considered was that there is no significant difference between before and after readings for each element.

However, into further reading into the chapter, the wilcoxon matched-pair signed rank test looks a better option since it considers not only the direction (plus and minus) but also the magnitude. And I think it makes sense for my case.

But I'm still talking about a 1956 reference, so I wish to know if there is a different test that can be used with the same purpose that is also more recent and common. I couldn't find the answer to this after some search, and as I don't have a statistical background I didn't know where to look properly.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Please adopt the habit of demarcating acronyms.

Comment: What issue are you seeking robustness against and why do you think that a signed rank test would offer more of this kind of robustness?

Comment: There is an extensive literature on [compositional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/compositional-data/info), which is what you have (all measurements add up to 100% for each sample). It's not clear that any generic "robust" test is what you need. You need statistical procedures that are designed for proportion data that necessarily add up to 1. This is outside my expertise, but there are [over 100 questions on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compositional-data) and a [website](http://www.compositionaldata.com/) devoted to the topic.

Comment: @Glen_b Hello, upon talking to a professor, he gave me the impression the sign test wasn't enough, as if there is a better choice. An impression of being outdated. I forgot to mention h0 on post, just edited it in. How much the percentages decrease or increase is relevant information for me, not only if they are increasing or not, that's why I thought the wilcoxon ranked could be better in considering if there is significant difference or not, when I read about it

Comment: @EdM Thank you for this information! I will look into compositional data and how to work with it. It does fit the description of what I need

Comment: "How much" isn't a testing question, but one of estimation. I agree with EdM that it's likely to be better to use procedures suitable for compositional data.

Comment: Since you are dealing with percentages that must add up to 100% the sum of differences between before and after will equal 0.  Thus why the sign test and match-pair test were not significant.  If you have enough data then maybe a pair t-test for each element might be the best.